# What is static site generation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, ssg

I know that static site generation idea, The question here is, if SSG gets fetched data at build time, in my next app I used an event handler to get some data according to the search keyword, and it works, How.

This is my code:
Below is the code for the Input component in the next weather app and I use **handleSubmit** event handler, It gets weather data from an API endpoint.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import axios from "axios";

function Input({ onInput }) {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState();
  const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = useState("أخل اسم البلد أو المنطقة...");

  return (
    <form className="hstack gap-3" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control me-auto"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={inputText || ""}
        onChange={handleInput}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
      />
      <button type="submit">ابحث</button>

      <style jsx>{`
        input {
          height: 50px;
          border-radius: 10px;
          color: var(--input-color);
          font-weight: 500;
          font-size: 1.1em;
          direction: rtl;
        }
        input:focus-visible {
          color: var(--input-color);
          font-weight: 500;
          font-size: 1.1em;
        }
        input:focus {
          box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem var(--input-shadow-color);
        }
        input::placeholder {
          color: var(--input-placeholder-color);
          font-weight: 500;
          opacity: 0.7;
        }
        button {
          padding: 0.60em 1.3em;
          background-color: var(--search-btn-background-color);
          color: #fff;
          font-weight: 500;
          border: 5px solid var(--search-btn-border-color);
          background-color: var(--search-btn-background-color);
          border-radius: 12px;
          transition: 0.5s;
        }
        button:hover {
          color: #fff;
          background-color: var(--btn-hover-color);
        }
        button:focus {
          box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem var(--search-btn-shadow-color);
        }
      `}</style>
    </form>
  );

  function handleFocus() {
    setPlaceholder("");
  }

  function handleBlur() {
    setPlaceholder("أخل اسم البلد أو المنطقة...");
  }

  function handleInput(event) {
    setInputText(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${inputText}&units=metric&appid=5a60c3e5c70d9f4ad304b2b115b3bf72&lang=ar`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        onInput(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        onInput(0);
      });

    setInputText("");
  }
}

Input.propTypes = {
  onInput: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default Input;
```

Comment: A statically generated site can still be interactive. You're adding code to run in response to users interaction on the client-side.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, now I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

SSG in NextJS only happens for queries inside a [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props) function.

In you example, your query is inside the component, so no query is performed at build time, but at run time as usual, so your search feature is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, now I understand